# Pandas concatenate dataframe with multiindex retaining index names

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a list of DataFrames as follows where each DataFrame in the list is as follows:

```
dfList[0]
monthNum        1      2 
G1                                
2.0           0.05  -0.16
3.0           1.17   0.07
4.0           9.06   0.83

dfList[1]
monthNum        1      2 
G2                                
21.0           0.25   0.26
31.0           1.27   0.27
41.0           9.26   0.23

dfList[0].index
Float64Index([2.0, 3.0, 4.0], dtype='float64', name='G1')
dfList[0].columns
Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64', name='monthNum')
```

I am trying to achieve the following in a dataframe `Final_Combined_DF`:

```
monthNum        1      2 
G1                                
2.0           0.05  -0.16
3.0           1.17   0.07
4.0           9.06   0.83
G2                                
21.0           0.25   0.26
31.0           1.27   0.27
41.0           9.26   0.23
```

I tried doing different combinations of:
`pd.concat(dfList, axis=0)`

but it has not given me desired output. I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Index names are not data in the DataFrame (more akin to labels), you could add `keys` to concat `final_combined_df = pd.concat(df_list, keys=map(lambda d: d.index.name, df_list))` but you'd end up with a MultiIndex which _would_ be data in the DataFrame. What are you trying to do? Are you looking to modify the _data_ of the frame, or alter the _display_?

Comment: Modify the data of the frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `keys` using the [`Index.name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.name.html) from each DataFrame to add a new level index in the final frame:

```
final_combined_df = pd.concat(
    df_list, keys=map(lambda d: d.index.name, df_list)
)
```

`final_combined_df`:

```
monthNum  0  1
G1 2.0    4  7
   3.0    7  1
   4.0    9  5
G2 21.0   8  1
   31.0   1  8
   41.0   2  6
```

---

Setup Used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
df_list = [
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 2)),
                 columns=pd.Index([0, 1], name='monthNum'),
                 index=pd.Index([2.0, 3.0, 4.0], name='G1')),
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 2)),
                 columns=pd.Index([0, 1], name='monthNum'),
                 index=pd.Index([21.0, 31.0, 41.0], name='G2'))
]
```

`df_list`:

```
[monthNum  0  1
G1            
2.0       4  7
3.0       7  1
4.0       9  5, 
 monthNum  0  1
G2            
21.0      8  1
31.0      1  8
41.0      2  6]
```